# How can I use awk (or cut) to print the last field per line from a pipe separated file?

Tags: linux, awk, cut

I have a file like that

```
14618   | 184.72.251.121   | 184.72.128.0/17     | US | arin     | 2010-01-26 | AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
14618   | 107.21.223.240   | 107.21.128.0/17     | US | arin     | 2011-05-03 | AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
16509   | 52.85.180.156    | 52.85.180.0/23      | US | arin     |            | AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
61337   | 85.199.214.99    | 85.199.212.0/22     | GB | ripencc  | 2005-02-08 | ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
31034   | 94.177.187.22    | 94.177.160.0/19     | IT | ripencc  | 2008-08-14 | ARUBA-ASN, IT
8816    | 212.45.144.206   | 212.45.128.0/19     | IT | ripencc  |            | IT-STCOM, IT
```

I must extract the last field and all its content. Notice that sometimes the penultimate column is empty.

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " "}; {for(i=13;i<NF;++i) print $i}'
```

but sometimes it doesn't work or it misses some words.

Can you help me please?

Comment: can you please add expected output so that it is clear what you need? a simple `awk -F'\|' '{print $NF}'` might be what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 awk -F'|' '{print $NF}' file
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
 ARUBA-ASN, IT
 IT-STCOM, IT
```

If this is not your desired output then please post your expected output.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome @Valonqar :)

Answer (score 2):

With sed: substitute the longest match up to `|` by nothing.

```
$ sed 's/.*|//' infile
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
 ARUBA-ASN, IT
 IT-STCOM, IT
```

If you don't want the leading blanks, remove them as well:

```
$ sed 's/.*|[[:blank:]]*//' infile
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
ARUBA-ASN, IT
IT-STCOM, IT
```

This matches up to the last `|` and includes as many blanks as possible after the `|`, then removes the match.

Answer (score 1):

Revert each line, read the first column with cut, revert back:

```
rev input | cut -f1 -d\| | rev
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it but it seems kinda convoluted and it'll leave a leading blank char compared to using just `sed 's/.*| //' input` or similar so maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would be better off using `awk` with the `|` character as the field separator (`awk -F'|'`) but, if they're always going to be nicely lined up like that, `cut` may well be a better option:

```
cut -c81- inputFile
```

That would give you all the characters from position 81 onwards in each line, which is *roughly* right just from me eyeballing the data. A bit of trial and error would give a more accurate value to use in place of `81` since I may be off by a couple - my eyeballs aren't as young as they once were :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you just want the 7th `|`-delimited field of your input:

```
cut -d\| -f7
```

```
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
 ARUBA-ASN, IT
 IT-STCOM, IT
```

If you want to get rid of the leading space, you can remove that with `cut` too:

```
cut -d\| -f7- | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by the last field you mean the last column. This is what you need:

```
awk -F'\|' '{print $7}' MyFile
```

It will print the last column of your file in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[^|]*$' file
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
 ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
 ARUBA-ASN, IT
 IT-STCOM, IT
```

If you don't want leading spaces:

```
grep -o '[^|]*$' file | cut -d' ' -f2-
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
ARUBA-ASN, IT
IT-STCOM, IT
```

You can also use Bash parameter expansion:

```
$ while read -r line; do echo ${line##*|}; done <file
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-AES - Amazon.com, Inc., US
AMAZON-02 - Amazon.com, Inc., US
ECOM-AS ============================================, GB
ARUBA-ASN, IT
IT-STCOM, IT
```